# How to add 301 redirects to NUXT

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a NUXT project which i'm trying to add 301 redirect to. I've tried a few different approaches, but nothing works. If I go to the old URL I get a 404 page.

Whats the best way to add redirects to a Nuxt project?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 const redirects =
 [
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/article/new-guidelines-new-normal-new-opportunities-new-working-environments', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/article/vetting-candidate-why-its-a-no-brainer', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/job-alerts', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/jobs', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/news', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/login', to: 'https://www. example.com' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/cv-upload', to: 'https://www. example.com/#submit-cv' },
   { from: 'https://www. example.com/expertise', to: 'https://www. example.com/our-expertise' }
 ]
 
  module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
   const redirect = redirects.find(r => r.from === req.url)
   if (redirect) {
     console.log(`redirect: ${redirect.from} => ${redirect.to}`)
     res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
     res.end()
   } else {
     next()
   }
 }

// nuxt.connig.js

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: "/api/redirects", handler: "~/api/redirects/index.js" },
  ],
```

Comment: So you want for example, that `/jobs` redirects you to `/`? Does it need to be on the server side?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a serverMiddleware that does the job.

```js
// nuxt.config.js
serverMiddleware: [{ 
      path: '/',
      handler: './serverMiddleware.js'
  }]
```

```js
// serverMiddleware.js
export default (req, res, next) => {
  // detect urls you'd like to redirect
  // call res.redirect(CODE, NEWURL)

  if (req.url === '/some-page/') {
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: 'redirect-page' });
    res.end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

You can also use the [Nuxt Redirect Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/redirect-module)

```
// nuxt.config.js
redirect: [
  { from: '^/myoldurl', to: '/mynewurl', statusCode: 301 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks Braks, but just tried this and nothing happens when hitting the URL I want to redirect.

Comment: I updated my response, seems that I had a wrong api for the serverMiddleware in mind.
Try the updated response out and let me know if that works for you.
Edit: I didn't even notice that you literally did the exact same thing already, sorry :D Been switching between questions too much.
What exactly is not working with your original implementation? (by the way you have some whitespaces in your routes? ** www .example **

Comment: Thanks for the help Braks. In the end using Nuxt Redirect Module did the tick!

Comment: You will need to add a call to `next()` in serverMiddleware.js for this code to work

Answer (score 7):

For **Nuxt 3** you can use the `routeRules` setting in your `nuxt.config.ts`.

**nuxt.config.ts**

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  routeRules: {
    "/from": {
        redirect: {
          to: "/to",
          statusCode: 301,
        },
    },
  },
});
```

For more config options see https://nitro.unjs.io/config/#routes

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted – this is correct for Nuxt 3. https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/rendering#hybrid-rendering

Comment: I am redirecting from my nuxt landing pages to my dashboard pages, which is a different project. Therefore I am ussing https://website/settings. How can I make it so that the query in the url doesn't go away?

Comment: Is it also possible to redirect multiple pages? For example /from/** to test.website/**

Comment: Note that Hybrid Rendering is not available when using nuxt generate.

Answer (score 0):

check https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect
however serverMiddleware property runs server-side before vue-server-renderer and can be used for server specific tasks like handling API requests or serving assets
my approach is routes middleware which are called before each route by Vue in Client Side or SSR
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-middleware