# 301 redirect in NuxtJS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, http-status-code-301

I am trying to work out a way to make 301 redirects in NuxtJS.
Is there a way to use router push and make it act/perform like a 301?

I currently have this

```
this.$router.push(`/${this.res.goTo}`);
```

in my mounted() function, this is good but it does not tell the browser it's a 301 (network tab)

Now, is there a way to redirect to another page and tell the browser it's a 301?

Using nuxtjs with SSR.

Comment: A redirect is only doable on the server (hence on the initial page render), when you're navigating client side, you can only perform an URL change via the Vue router.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add 301 redirects to NUXT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68415572/how-to-add-301-redirects-to-nuxt)

Comment: @Jimmar I looked that up, but I can't use .env variables in the serverMiddleware, so that makes it unusable :/